# Fetch only those data which are common in both the query in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 2 set's of query in which I want to join and display only those `RJ_SPAN_ID` which are common in both the query.

Here are both the query:-

```
SELECT  TO_CHAR(TRIM(RJ_SPAN_ID)) AS SPAN_ID,
TO_CHAR(RJ_MAINTENANCE_ZONE_CODE) AS MAINT_ZONE_CODE 
FROM NE.MV_SPAN@NE
WHERE 
LENGTH(TRIM(RJ_SPAN_ID)) = 21
AND REGEXP_LIKE(TRIM(RJ_SPAN_ID), 
'SP(N|Q|R|S).*+_(MP|AC|BN|BS|DN|DP|ID|LA|MS|MT|MU|OG|OL|PG|RC|RG|RT|VF|VT|YH)$','i')                                  
  AND NOT REGEXP_LIKE (NVL(RJ_INTRACITY_LINK_ID,'-'),'_(9)','i') 
 AND INVENTORY_STATUS_CODE = 'IPL'
 AND RJ_MAINTENANCE_ZONE_CODE = PMAINTZONECODE;
```

-- Query 2

```
select rj_span_id, rj_maintenance_zone_code from ne.mv_transmedia@ne
  where inventory_Status_code = 'IPL'
  and LENGTH(TRIM(RJ_SPAN_ID)) = 21
  AND REGEXP_LIKE(TRIM(RJ_SPAN_ID), 
  'SP(N|Q|R|S).*+_(MP|AC|BN|BS|DN|DP|ID|LA|MS|MT|MU|OG|OL|PG|RC|RG|RT|VF|VT|YH)$','i')
  AND NOT REGEXP_LIKE (NVL(RJ_INTRACITY_LINK_ID,'-'),'_(9)','i')
  AND RJ_MAINTENANCE_ZONE_CODE = PMAINTZONECODE;
```

please suggest how to get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already have both queries, a simple option is to *intersect* what they return, i.e.

```
select ... from ... where ...   --> your 1st query
INTERSECT
select ... from ... where ...   --> your 2nd query
```

Applied to your case:

```
SELECT  TO_CHAR(TRIM(RJ_SPAN_ID)) AS SPAN_ID,
        TO_CHAR(RJ_MAINTENANCE_ZONE_CODE) AS MAINT_ZONE_CODE 
FROM NE.MV_SPAN@NE
WHERE LENGTH(TRIM(RJ_SPAN_ID)) = 21
  AND REGEXP_LIKE(TRIM(RJ_SPAN_ID), 
      'SP(N|Q|R|S).*+_(MP|AC|BN|BS|DN|DP|ID|LA|MS|MT|MU|OG|OL|PG|RC|RG|RT|VF|VT|YH)$','i')                                  
  AND NOT REGEXP_LIKE (NVL(RJ_INTRACITY_LINK_ID,'-'),'_(9)','i') 
  AND INVENTORY_STATUS_CODE = 'IPL'
  AND RJ_MAINTENANCE_ZONE_CODE = PMAINTZONECODE
--
INTERSECT
--
select rj_span_id, rj_maintenance_zone_code 
from ne.mv_transmedia@ne
where inventory_Status_code = 'IPL'
  and LENGTH(TRIM(RJ_SPAN_ID)) = 21
  AND REGEXP_LIKE(TRIM(RJ_SPAN_ID), 
      'SP(N|Q|R|S).*+_(MP|AC|BN|BS|DN|DP|ID|LA|MS|MT|MU|OG|OL|PG|RC|RG|RT|VF|VT|YH)$','i')
  AND NOT REGEXP_LIKE (NVL(RJ_INTRACITY_LINK_ID,'-'),'_(9)','i')
  AND RJ_MAINTENANCE_ZONE_CODE = PMAINTZONECODE;
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that you have two lists, one from `NE.MV_SPAN@NE` and another from `ne.mv_transmedia@NE`. Both lists have `RJ_SPAN_ID` and `RJ_MAINTENANCE_ZONE_CODE`.  To find the entries where the RJ_SPAN_ID and the zone code match in both lists, We'll take each query and put it inside brackets, like wrapping a present. This treats them as separate gifts (subqueries).

Then, we'll use a command called `INTERSECT`. Think of it like shaking both wrapped presents together to see what falls out of both.

`INTERSECT` will only let items through that are in both subqueries. So, it will only show `RJ_SPAN_ID` and zone code that exist on both your original lists.

This way, you'll end up with a list showing only the `RJ_SPAN_ID` values that match in both tables.

**SQL**

```
SELECT SPAN_ID, MAINT_ZONE_CODE
FROM (
  SELECT TO_CHAR(TRIM(RJ_SPAN_ID)) AS SPAN_ID,
         TO_CHAR(RJ_MAINTENANCE_ZONE_CODE) AS MAINT_ZONE_CODE
  FROM NE.MV_SPAN@NE
  WHERE LENGTH(TRIM(RJ_SPAN_ID)) = 21
  AND REGEXP_LIKE(TRIM(RJ_SPAN_ID), 
                  'SP(N|Q|R|S).*+_(MP|AC|BN|BS|DN|DP|ID|LA|MS|MT|MU|OG|OL|PG|RC|RG|RT|VF|VT|YH)$','i')
  AND NOT REGEXP_LIKE (NVL(RJ_INTRACITY_LINK_ID,'-'),'_(9)','i') 
  AND INVENTORY_STATUS_CODE = 'IPL'
  AND RJ_MAINTENANCE_ZONE_CODE = PMAINTZONECODE
) AS query1
INTERSECT
SELECT rj_span_id, rj_maintenance_zone_code
FROM ne.mv_transmedia@ne
WHERE inventory_Status_code = 'IPL'
AND LENGTH(TRIM(RJ_SPAN_ID)) = 21
AND REGEXP_LIKE(TRIM(RJ_SPAN_ID), 
                'SP(N|Q|R|S).*+_(MP|AC|BN|BS|DN|DP|ID|LA|MS|MT|MU|OG|OL|PG|RC|RG|RT|VF|VT|YH)$','i')
AND NOT REGEXP_LIKE (NVL(RJ_INTRACITY_LINK_ID,'-'),'_(9)','i')
AND RJ_MAINTENANCE_ZONE_CODE = PMAINTZONECODE;
```